# What is the Big Oh of these two implementations of the same algorithm?

Tags: algorithm

I am writing an algorithm which will return true if a string contains no duplicate characters, and false otherwise. I have two different implementations:

The first uses a hashmap:

```
public static boolean hasUniqueCharsFast(String s) {
    char[] input = s.toCharArray();
    Map<Character, Character> map = new HashMap<Character, Character>();
    for (char c: input) {
        if (map.get(c) != null) {
            return false;
        } else {
            map.put(c, c);
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

The second is in-place and compares each character will every other character:

```
public static boolean hasUniqueChars(String s) {
        char[] input = s.toCharArray();
        //Compare the string with everything but itself (i.e. ignore chars at same index)
        for (int i=0;i<input.length;i++) {
            for (int j=0;j<input.length;j++) {
                if (input[i] == input[j] && i != j ) {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Is it correct that the Big Oh of the first implementation is O(n), and the Big Oh of the second implementation is O(n^2)?

I guess the trade-offs are that the first one uses additional storage space, whereas the second implementation doesn't use additional storage (i.e. is in-place)?

Comment: And what is the question?

Answer (score 0):

> Is it correct that the Big Oh of the first implementation is O(n), and the Big Oh of the second implementation is O(n^2)?

Yes. Hash operations are considered to have constant cost.

> I guess the trade-offs are that the first one uses additional storage space, whereas the second implementation doesn't use additional storage (i.e. is in-place)?

Yes. You should also note that the constant value of the first is higher. But for large strings the first algorithm will crush the second.

Note that the code can be optimized to be almost twice as fast.

First algorithm (assuming `put` returns previous value, like in java):

```
public static boolean hasUniqueCharsFast(String s) {
    char[] input = s.toCharArray();
    Map<Character, Character> map = new HashMap<Character, Character>();
    for (char c: input) {
        if (map.put(c, c) != null) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Second algorithm:

```
public static boolean hasUniqueChars(String s) {
    char[] input = s.toCharArray();
    //Compare the string with everything but itself (i.e. ignore chars at same index)
    for (int i=0;i<input.length;i++) {
        for (int j=i+1;j<input.length;j++) {  // Changed starting index
            if (input[i] == input[j]) {       // Removed i == j check
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'You should also note that the constant value of the first is higher.'?

Comment: O(N) means that time < C*N where C is a constant. The first algorithm will have fairly large C while the second one has a small C. C1/C2 denotes the "break-even", the N for which the time limit is the same for the two algorithms. For short strings the second algorithm will be faster.